# What is the nicest way to weight planes in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have the following code in which w is a 1D numpy array of compatible dimension, and M is a 4D array,

```
i = 0
for weight in w:
    M[:, :, i, :] *= weight
    i += 1
```

Is there a nicer way to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are scaling `M` along `axis=2` with the elements from `w`, which is a `1D` array. So, you need to extend `w` to a 2D array with [`np.newaxis/None`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis), which will align the axes  between `extended version of w` with `M`. Then,  perform element-wise multiplication between these two arrays to bring in [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for a vectorized solution, like so -

```
M *= w[:,None]
```

If `axis=2` of `M` has a length that is more than the number of elements in `w`, you need to select a range along `axis=2` in `M` before multiplying, like so -

```
M[...,np.arange(w.size),:] *= w[:,None]
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on my trying to understand @Divakar's answer.
What helped me understand what is going on is writing their suggestion of

```
M *= w[:,None]
```

as

```
M *= w[None,None,:,None]
```

where now the dimensions of M and the extended w are visibly the same. Of course, @Divakar's version is shorter and so more elegant, but less intuitive.

So, a full working example would be:

```
import numpy as np
M = np.ones((1,4,3,2))
w = np.arange(3)
M *= w[None,None,:,None]
print M
```

Comment: Thanks. I marked Divakar's version as correct since they are both correct and he was first. I prefer your more explicit way.

Comment: To be even more explicict you can replace `None` with `np.newaxis`: `M *= w[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]`